# Split foreach code based on even/odd

Tags: html, magento, foreach, split

I currently use a code to display some content in my Magento shop.
But now I want to split the loaded content based on even/odd into two different divs.

My current code is displayed below.

How can I split the code based on even/odd so that I get to `<div class="block-specs">`.

I want a div `<div class="block-specs odd">` and `<div class="block-specs even">`

How can I achieve that?

Current code:

```
<?php if($_additionalgroup = $this->getAdditionalData()): ?>
<section id="additional">
<div class="box-collateral box-additional">
    <h2><?php echo $this->__('Additional Information') ?></h2>

    <?php $i=0; foreach ($_additionalgroup as $_additional): $i++; ?>
    <div class="block-specs-<?php echo $i?>">
        <h3 class="specs-<?php echo $i?>"><?php echo $this->__( $_additional['title'] )?></h3>
        <table class="data-table specs-<?php echo $i?>" id="product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>">
            <col width="25%" />
            <col />
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($_additional['items'] as $_data): ?>
             <?php $_attribute = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute($_data['code']);
    if (!is_null($_product->getData($_attribute->getAttributeCode())) && ((string)$_attribute->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) != '')) { ?>
                <tr>
                    <th class="label"><?php echo $this->htmlEscape($this->__($_data['label'])) ?></th>
                    <td class="data"><?php echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_data['value'], $_data['code']) ?></td>
                </tr>
            <?php } ?>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
        <script type="text/javascript">decorateTable('product-attribute-specs-table-<?php echo $i?>')</script>
    <?php endforeach; ?>

</div>
</section>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Check if the index is evenly divisable by 2 with '%' this returns the remainder after dividing (0 if even).

```
<?php foreach ($_additionalgroup as $i => $_additional): 
  // if evenly divisable by 2, it is even
  $oddEven =($i % 2) ? 'odd':'even';
?>

<div class="block-specs-<?php echo $oddEven; ?>">
```